# Break from inner loop batch

Tags: loops, batch-file, break

I have 3 nested loops, and I want to break from the third loop when a file having a certain pattern is found in a directory. I use the label "break" after each founded file, but the problem is that this methods exits from all 3 loops.`enter code here`

```
FOR /F "delims= " %%A in (file.txt) do (
  set pattern=%%A
  set file=""
  FOR /f "tokens=*" %%t in (
 'dir /a:d /b !DIR!'
  ) do (
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
    'dir /a:d /b "!DIR!\%%t"'
    ) do (
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%g in (
    'dir /b !DIR!\%%t\%%f ^| findstr /i /c:"!pattern!.inst"'
    ) do (
      set file=%%g
      echo "file: !file!"
      goto :break // BREAK
     )
    )
  ) 
  : break
  IF not [!file!] == [""] (
    echo "found !file!"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not. Any `goto` inside a for loop structure will cancel the loops.

If you only need the first element, you can test in the inner loop

```
if not defined file set "file==%%g"
```

or you can filter the output of the `dir` command to only feed the first line to the `for` command

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
    set "file="
    for /d %%t in ("!dir!\*"
    ) do for /d %%f in ("%%~ft\*"
    ) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%d in (
        'dir /b "%%~ff\*.inst*" ^| findstr /n /i /c:"%%a.inst" ^| findstr /b /c:"1:" '
    ) do set "file=%%e"

    if defined file echo found !file!
)
```

Anyway, not knowing the purpose of the code this is just an opinion, but it will be far more efficient to first retrieve the list of folder/files to consider into a temporary file and then iterate over it checking the retrieved information against the "patterns", instead of having to iterate the full folder structure for each of the patterns.

Comment: It takes too much time, because I have a long list of files and I wanted to exit after I find the first occurence. Tnanks for your answer. I have also found another solution, to make a subroutine containing the inner loop and call it from the third loop.

Comment: @georgiana_e, that is the reason for the approach of first retrieve the list and then process it. You will only iterate once over the file system. The next iteration will handle information from a file that already is inside the file cache. And, moving the third loop to a subroutine does not avoid the fact that the `for /f` loop needs to first retrieve all the data. That is, `dir|findstr` pipe has processed all the data before the code inside the `for` starts to execute.